# regular expression that matches seven numbers and an aphabet

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

When i did matching of 6 numbers it worked

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{6}$/',$keywords);
```

but when i tried adding match for a single letter it didn't worked can anyone help me.

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{6}[A-Z]{1}$/',$keywords);
```

Comment: Where the alphabet would be located?

Comment: what were the inputs that failed?

Comment: RegEx should work. Please provide example input.

Comment: 6 digits and one capital that is

Comment: @vks  the input is like this $keywords=123456A;

Comment: The regex works only if the letter is at the end of the string, the OP is asking for the letter to be able to appear anywhere. So the questions is: RegEx that matches a string of 6 digits and 1 letter while the letter can be placed anywhere.

Comment: @frlan the input is like this $keywords=123456A;

Comment: works here https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/7

Comment: i want to match  a string that start with 6 digits and ends with a capital or small letter

Answer (score 2):

> RegEx that matches a string of 6 digits and 1 letter while the letter can be placed anywhere.

```
^(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*$)[\dA-Za-z]{7}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/8)

> i want to match a string that start with 6 digits and ends with a capital or small letter

```
^\d{6}[A-Za-z]$
```

Comment: Something is either wrong with your first regex or with the tester, when I enter this: "123456y
f123456
456n432
1234567
a", the "1234567" is marked as a match, but only when the "a" is present?

Comment: add newline character inside the character class https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/11 . For testing single strings, it won't produce any problems

Answer (score 0):

I think it can not be done with pure RegEx. But using the string length, you could do this:

```
if(strlen($string) === 7 && prey_match('/^[0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*$/', $string) {
```

The RegEx checks for one letter surrounded by any number of digits, the strlen check makes sure that the string length is 7, making the string 6 digits and 1 letter.

### Edit

I stand corrected, Avinash Raj posted a RegEx that actually can do that.